# How to fix bash script to find regex in another file?

Tags: regex, bash

I have tried the following file to find a certain regex in a file and echo out some output

```
content=`cat $1 `

REGEX_RANGE="s/COPYRIGHT .*[0-9]{4}-[0-9]{4} alex4200"
REGEX_SINGLE="s/COPYRIGHT .*[0-9]{4} alex4200"

if [[ $content =~ $REGEX_RANGE ]];
then
    echo "File has year range"
else
    if [[ $content =~ $REGEX_SINGLE ]];
    then
        echo "File has single year"
    else
        echo "No REGEX found"
    fi
fi
```

However, when I use this script on a file `test.txt` with the content

```
COPYRIGHT (c) 2020 alex4200
```

it returns `No REGEX found`. What am I missing here?

Comment: I didn't downvote but BASH regex doesn't support `\d` Use `[0-9]` or `[[:digit:]]`.

Comment: Does not seem to matter. Question updated

Comment: Need to remove `s/` from regex

Comment: Yes thanks, that was it. It really is very complicated, as every command (bash, sed, grep, python) seems to have its own regex rules...

Comment: `grep -E 'COPYRIGHT .*[0-9]{4}-[0-9]{4} alex4200' file` is more suitable for this

Comment: @anubhava That does not seem to work, i.e. something like `if grep -q -E 'COPYRIGHT .*[0-9]{4}-[0-9]{4} alex4200' file; then
 echo "yeah"
fi`

Comment: `2020` does not match `[0-9]{4}-[0-9]{4}`. Use the single.

Answer (score 0):

Your pattern works, though maybe not as you intended.

```
$: grep -E 'COPYRIGHT .*[0-9]{4}-[0-9]{4} alex4200' file
COPYRIGHT (c) 2020-9999 alex4200
$: grep -E 'COPYRIGHT .*[0-9]{4} alex4200' file
COPYRIGHT (c) 2020 alex4200
COPYRIGHT (c) 2020-9999 alex4200
```

Your single rexex will match both formats; the `.*` eats not only the `(c)` and following space but also the first year and dash in a range pattern.

```
$: if grep -qE 'COPYRIGHT .*[0-9]{4} alex4200' file; then echo found; else echo nope; fi
found
```